# Reversing the effect of `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am working on an application where user can create HTML templates and save them to the database.The templates consist of different components like text,image etc.When I try to save the text with an **apostrophe** `'` it gives me `mysql_error` (obviously).So I tried `mysqli_real_escape_strings` to nulify it.It worked,but I want to get back the saved content for **editing purpose** and the apostrophe's are escaped using `\`(slashes).So the content is modified internally and is no more a valid html to edit and the browser throws a syntax error.
       
    I also tried searching other functions for escaping and came across `json_encode` but that is not accepted by mysql.
Can someone point me to any function which would do this in php?Please suggest any function that would carry out the task for me!

**Update:**

```
  function saveContent(){   
    var $getContent = $('#mainWrap').clone();
    $getContent.find('.textBox, .pictureBox').removeAttr('id');
    var saveContent  = $getContent.wrap('<div></div>').html();
    console.log(saveContent);
    var getBodyStyle=$('body').attr('style');
    console.log('this is body style'+getBodyStyle);
    var auto="auto";
    $.ajax({
        url:"auto_save.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"text",
        //data:"txtComp="+saveContent+"&auto="+auto+"&pageId="+pageId+"&webId="+webId+"&userId="+userId+"&bodyStyle="+getBodyStyle,
        data: {txtComp: saveContent, auto: auto, pageId: pageId,webId:webId,userId:userId,bodyStyle:getBodyStyle}
    }); 
 }
```

I add the `mysql_real_escape_string` in my `auto_save.php`. Now when I fetch it back from DB,I have to pass it to a javascript variable like this.

```
    var getSavedContent = <?php echo json_encode($IdLessContent); ?>;
```

Can that be an issue?

Comment: [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes data so that it can be used in a query, it does not affect what is stored in the table. Check your `magic_quotes_gpc` setting and disable it, this might have caused the error

Comment: **`stripslashes`** would also remove slashes from the text I have and don't want to be removed..right?

Comment: yes, you don't want to reverse `mysqli_real_escape_string` at all. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @fab Does disabling the setting have any adverse impact on the system or application??Can it be done on production servers?

Comment: You don't need to use one. You should only ever use mysql_escape_string just before putting something into a MySQL query. When the data come back out of the database, they will be in their original form.

Comment: it should have been disabled from the beginning, in new PHP versions it does not even exist anymore. You might have a problem with very old legacy applicacions that rely on the setting but it is not even safe, so then you have a problem anyway ;)

Comment: I am transfering my variable with content from php to javascript.Can that cause a problem?Adding my code to the question!

Comment: As others have said, you should not need to 'reverse' `mysqli_real_escape_string`. If you've used it properly, then fetching the data back from the DB won't have the escape characters in it. If you do have escape characters in your saved DB string, then you need to fix how you're saving to the DB, not try to reverse the damage afterward.

Comment: by the way, please let us know what PHP version you're using; this may be relevant here.

Comment: updated my question.Can you please have a look??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stripslashes()` will remove slashes from any string, and is useful when outputting escaped data.

I believe you need to use this:

`json_encode($IdLessContent, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

with the UNESCAPED_SLASHES part, your data should be returned correctly.

Comment: stripslashes would also remove slashes from the text I have and don't want to be removed..right?

Comment: Yes, all slashes. See the comment above about `magic_quotes_gpc` and also http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php - you may be able to avoid the problem to start with :)

Comment: However if you already had a backslash that was escaped, your form would output it as a double slash \\, so stripslashes would only strip one of them, leaving a single \

Comment: I get an error `SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

var getSavedContent   = <br />`.Also tried to keep everything in quotes,but didn't work!

Comment: Something in your HTML and content is probably terminating the javascript statment and causing a syntax error - this is typically why it escapes it in the first place. I think the best thing you can do is store the escaped data in a string, and then use a javascript function to unescape it when you come to use the code in your application.

Comment: I did not get you completely.I got `to store it in a string`,but to unescape it in javascript,I didn't get it!!Sorry but still learning these things

Comment: I had to remove the `single quotes` around the `json_encode` function to make it working

Comment: `json_encode($IdLessContent, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)` does not work, see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

The effect of `mysqli_real_escape_string` **doesn't** have to be reversed. All escaping is done for SQL query and never stored in the database. The only reason for getting slashes back is doing escaping twice.

In a properly-written application, there shouldn't be any escaping at all.  You should be using PDO with parameter binding to handle any escaping automatically.

I only created the following function to handle some legacy code that was escaping twice and I needed a way to get back to the original data.

```
function reverse_mysqli_real_escape_string($str) {
    return strtr($str, [
        '\0'   => "\x00",
        '\n'   => "\n",
        '\r'   => "\r",
        '\\\\' => "\\",
        "\'"   => "'",
        '\"'   => '"',
        '\Z' => "\x1a"
    ]);
 }
```

Comment: It was correct in February 2013. That was 6 years ago. You do understand things change over time? If you're going to say 'its incorrect', state what version you're referring to.

Comment: It is incorrect for the current version of PHP 7.3, I have no way of knowing what version you were running six years ago.